# Adjusting Brightness, OpenCV and c++

Tags: c++, opencv, brightness

I wanted to know if there is any function of OpenCV using C++ to adjust the brightness and contrast of a video / frame. You can convert from BGR color space to HSV color space, and discard the latter component V (luminance) to make the algorithm less sensitive to light conditions in the video, but how can I do it?

I was thinking of using something like cvAddS (frame, cvScalar (-50, -50, -50), frame) to Decrease the brightness, cvAddS and cvScalar work's well for C but how can I do that for C++, I use AddS and Scalar in my program, but don't work with C++

```
int main() {
    VideoCapture video(1);
    if(!video.isOpened()) {
        cerr<<"No video input"<<endl; return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    for(;;) {
        Mat frame;
        video >> frame; if(!frame.data) break;
        Mat frame2;
        //I USE AddS AND Scalar TO DECREASE THE BRIGHTNESS
        AddS(frame,Scalar(-50,-50,-50),frame2);
        //BUT DON'T WORK WITH C++
        imshow("Video",frame2);

        int c=waitKey(20);

        if(c >= 0)break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [matrix expression](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions):

```
cv::Mat frame2 = frame + cv::Scalar(-50, -50, -50);
```

You might also want to adjust the contrast with [histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization). Convert your RGB image to HSV and apply [`cv::equalizeHist()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#equalizehist) to the V channel.

Answer (score 3):

Brightness and contrast are usually corrected using a linear transformation of the pixel values. Brightness corresponds to the additive shift and contrast corresponds to a multiplicative factor.

In general, given a pixel value `v`, the new value after to correction would be `v'=a*v + b`.

Comment: this info isnt written excplicitly in the tutorials, thank you.